# Top navigation bar and footer position without messing up rest of page without using any libraries and frameworks

Tags: css, navbar, footer

I am running always to same issues with top navigation bar and footer. I always have problem to place them on the correct position.

Top nav : the logo should be on top left and rest align to right

Footer: is in the middle of the page even though I followed a recommendation and created main container for all divs on my page.

CSS & image attached to the question

```css
html,body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
   color: #696969;
}
#mainContainer{
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

header{
    background-color:#F8F8F8;
    height: 120px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
    display: flex;
}

.topnav {
    margin-left: 12%;
    margin-right: 12%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    position: absolute;
   align-items: flex-start;
   float: right;
}

.topnav a {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    color: #343434;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}


.topnav a.active {
    color: #4CAF50;
}

.sidebar {
    margin-left: 12%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 12%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }
.sidebar a {
    display: block;
    color: #696969;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
    border-right: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
}

section {
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 12%;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
}



#footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    color: #696969;
}

footer { 
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
    border-top: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
}
.rights{
    text-align:left;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

.socialnets{
    text-align:center;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}


.newsletter{
    text-align:right;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: add your html too and complete the snippet for us to check the issues :)

Answer (score 0):

setting 100% height on body inherits from viewport essentially. thats why the footer is fixed at the bottom of the pixel value for your viewport and if you scroll, it doesn't 'stick'.

I'm guessing this is what you want?..

I have no idea what structure your html is so this is just going off your css.

I would advise looking at flexbox and checking out the sticky footer method using flex.
https://codepen.io/devatrox/pen/wztlx

```css
html,body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   min-height:100vh;
   height:100%;
   color: #696969;
}
#mainContainer{
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

header{
    background-color:#F8F8F8;
    height: 120px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
    display: flex;
}

.topnav {
    margin-left: 12%;
    margin-right: 12%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    position: absolute;
   align-items: flex-start;
   float: right;
}

.topnav a {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    color: #343434;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}


.topnav a.active {
    color: #4CAF50;
}

.sidebar {
    margin-left: 12%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 12%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: red;
    height: calc(100% - 121px);
}


.sidebar a {
    display: block;
    color: #696969;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
    border-right: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
}

section {
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 12%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
}



#footer{
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    color: #696969;
background-color:blue;
}

footer { 
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
    border-top: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
}
.rights{
    text-align:left;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

.socialnets{
    text-align:center;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}


.newsletter{
    text-align:right;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer"><header><div class="topnav">top</div></header><div class="sidebar">side</div><section>Content <h1>heading</h1><p>TExt or stuff idk</p></section><section>Content <h1>heading</h1><p>TExt or stuff idk</p></section><section>Content <h1>heading</h1><p>TExt or stuff idk</p></section>
<div id="footer">FOOTER</footer>
```